# How do I show math block inside list in github readme?

Tags: markdown

I tried this:

````
1. Setup
        1. item 1:
```math
                \left( \{g^{s^k}\}_{k\in[d]}, \{g_l^{l_i(s)}, g_r^{r_i(s)}, g_o^{o_i(s)}\}_{i\in\{0,...,n\}}, \\
                \{g_l^{α_{l}l_i(s)}, g_r^{α_{r}r_i(s)}, g_o^{α_{o}o_i(s)}, g_l^{βl_i(s)}g_r^{βr_i(s)}g_o^{βo_i(s)}\}_{i\in\{m+1,...,n\}}, \\
                g_l^{t(s)}, g_r^{t(s)}, g_o^{t(s)}, g_l^{α_{l}t(s)}, g_r^{α_{r}t(s)}, g_o^{α_{o}t(s)}, g_l^{βt(s)}, g_r^{βt(s)}, g_o^{βt(s)}  \right)
```extraly_added_not_exist_in_OP
        2. item 2
````

But it breaks the display of "item 2", which is supposed to be aligned with "item 1", now becomes aligned with the parent item, demo [here](https://github.com/blockchaindevsh/try/blob/master/readme.md)

What's the correct way to make both math and list look normal?

Comment: How exactly is this related to LaTeX and friends? This seems more of a markdown issue.